# How to do triple/quadruple join using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Basically I have 4 main entities table and 3 association tables ordered in this way:

- Library: ID,
- Association1: LibraryID, CategoryID
- Category: ID, Name
- Association2: CategoryID, BookID
- Book: ID, Name
- Association3:BookID, AuthorID
- Author: ID, Name

How to join all the above table to form only 1 with all details in, using SQL?

I using SQL Server btw.

Comment: `...FROM tbl1 t1 join tbl2 t2 on tbl1.ID=tbl2.ID join tbl3 t3 on tbl1.ID=tbl3.ID`

Comment: Do main-table LEFT JOIN other table LEFT JOIN other table etc.

Comment: @Avan CaiJun, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @EduardUta I have tried looking for Left join examples, but if it is a star design, I can easily concat left join to the main table. But in my case is a chain relationship. So I concur that I would need to have nested left join but I dunno how should I even start.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the path...

```
SELECT *
FROM Library l -- ID, Name 
LEFT JOIN Association1 a1 -- LibraryID, CategoryID
ON l.ID = a1.LibraryID
LEFT JOIN Category c -- ID, Name
ON a1.CategoryID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Association2 a2 -- CategoryID, BookID
ON c.ID = a2.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN Book b -- ID, Name
ON a2.BookID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Association3 a3 -- BookID, AuthorID
ON b.ID = a3.BookID
LEFT JOIN Author au -- ID, NAME
ON a3.AuthorID = au.ID
```

Plus, take a look on this (at least): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191430(v=sql.105).aspx